# taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection never called

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to get the redirect link from my post request but after upgraded to alamofire 4.3.0 my delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection has never called.
What I'm doing wrong?

I'm calling this way:

```
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
let delegate: Alamofire.SessionDelegate = sessionManager.delegate

delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { session, task, response, request in
    let headers = response.allHeaderFields
    MYUrlConstant.redirectLocation = headers["Location"]! as! String
    return URLRequest(url: URL(string: MYUrlConstant.redirectLocation)!)
}

Alamofire.request("http://test.com", method: .post, parameters: nil).responseJSON {}
```

Comment: did you fixed it? I have same issue in Alamofire 4.3.0

Comment: Yeah.. See my answer bellow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem: has not used the declared manager to make a call who I expected the redirection.
Example:

```
 let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    let delegate: Alamofire.SessionDelegate = SessionDelegate.init()

    manager!.delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { session, task, response, request in
        let headers = response.allHeaderFields
        let redirectLocation = headers["Location"]! as! String
        return URLRequest(url: URL(string: redirectLocation)!)
    }

//make your call with your manager delcared
manager!.request("url", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {    
}
```

Comment: Thnx a lot!
And please edit your code, there is a sessionManager and manager misleading.